# Problem during installation

Tags: elementary-website

After clicking full installation of Elementary os on new DOS Laptop, the logo of elementary os appeared​, and it's 4hrs and it is still there, nothing is happening.
[image: Here is the image]

Comment: omg, dude you must provide more information than that, help us for helping you, first of all what kind of laptop on these days are still using DOS that OS was deprecated since 80's how can you even call that thing "new", then the problem for that is that the USB key is loading something try pressing [DOWN] key for seeing the input instead of that logo, and update the question properly

Comment: did you try to get into one of the virtual consoles? (ie not gui mode) ... sorry forgot to tell you how ... note this works for me on a desktop ... {Ctl}{Alt} {F1 key} ... then you might be able to do a dmesg | tail -20 to see what the system is logging

Comment: Try installing again.

Comment: Show us the UEFI settings, scpecially Boot and Hard-disk/Devices

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem on a quite new machine (Asus UX410UA). After pressing Esc there is no bootlog. It's hanged. Other distros are booting normally. The most interresting thing is when loki 0.4.1 arrived I tried to boot it and it worked. Now it does not (I redownloaded it). Sha sums are correct, it's not corrupted. Liveusb was created by dd command. It is booting in virtualbox.
Nomodeset doesn't work.